# How to connect service from CF to application in AWS in application flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, ssh-tunnel

I have cloud foundry rabbitMQ sitting in some cloud or on-prem and application in AWS.

These are on different network.
I want to access rabbitMQ for workers in AWS.
According to CF services, I can use SSH connection to service from another network.
But

1. Can we use SSH tunnel in application flow in production?
2. How reliable is it?
3. What will happen at scale ? will all SSH tunnel end up on the same machine in clustered RabbitMQ?

Anybody has used such scenario? and how to tackle it?

As rabbitMQ is not over HTTP, we need some kind of TCP connection here which is difficult if server and worker are on different network.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue, however, if you're considering creating a reverse tunnel from a CF service instance in order for an instance on AWS to access it, I think you're doing it wrong ;-) Why not have your worker run on Cloud Foundry also, alongside the provisioned service.

Comment: because this is say hybrid cloud scenario